# FileSystemNotFoundException after Export

Tags: java, export

today i've a problem after the exportation (I'm using ecplise)
(My application work before export but not after)

Error screen: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/33/4/1565884882-capture.png

I've tried to export with others library handling options and its gave me that the same error but with more:

Error screen: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/33/4/1565885180-capture.png

Here is the class where my launch method is:

```java
package com.bleu.application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Bleu {

    public static void launch() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {


        File Bleu = new File("C:\\temp\\Bleu.exe");

        URL url = Bleu.class.getResource("Bleu.exe");
        Path source = Paths.get(url.toURI());

        Files.copy(source, Bleu.toPath());

       }
}
```

And there is the main class

```java
package com.bleu;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import com.bleu.application.Bleu;
import com.bleu.bootstrap.bootstrap;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    Checker.deleteExists();

    bootstrap.update();
    Bleu.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: With export you refer to what exactly? Creation of a `runnable jar`? I guess the error prettry much indicates that you try to look up the path of the `Bleu.exe` file from within your jar, which seems to be wrong (why would the `exe` be within the `jar` if you try to copy it).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, 

i'm refering the Runnable Jar export option no others and i don't know no why before exporting the project i have no error and the application work very well but
why after that don't work and make me an error. And i put the executable inside the jar then copy him and his .dll past them in annother folder outside the
jar because its the only way i found to run an executable with .dll dependencies (Because if i just run him without his .dll the application crash and do not run)

Comment: I assume the difference is that your `exe` was not in a `zipped` container. If you want to copy it outside the jar file, you'll want to `unzip` it first. So i suppose you'll probably want to have a folder that contains these things next to the jar instead and copy it from there.

Comment: Please include your exception stack traces as text in your question, not as links to images.  Images are hard to read, cannot be searched, and are useless to sight-impaired users.  External links eventually disappear, which will make your question useless to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem, thanks for your help

I used that:

```html
URI uri = getClass().getResource("myresourcefile.txt").toURI();

if("jar".equals(uri.getScheme())){
    for (FileSystemProvider provider: FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()) {
        if (provider.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("jar")) {
            try {
                provider.getFileSystem(uri);
            } catch (FileSystemNotFoundException e) {
                // in this case we need to initialize it first:
                provider.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap());
            }
        }
    }
}
Path source = Paths.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never assume a resource is a regular file.  If the resource is inside a .jar file, it’s just a subsequence of compressed bytes, not a true file.

Instead of trying to treat your resource as a Path, obtain it as an InputStream, and copy that InputStream instead:

```
Path bleu = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\Bleu.exe");

try (InputStream source = Bleu.class.getResourceAsStream("Bleu.exe")) {
    Files.copy(source, bleu);
}
```